# How to solve $y''+4y'+5y=\sin x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

> Solve $y''+4y'+5y=\sin x$.

The solution to the homogenous equation is:
$$
y_h(x)=c_1e^{-2x}\cos x+c_2e^{-2x}\sin x
$$
Using undetermined coefficients method we can guess that the particular solution will be of form:
$$
y_p(x)=a\cos x+b\sin x
$$
But $\cos x$ already appears in the homogenous solution so shouldn't the particular solution be $y_p(x)=x(a\cos x+b\sin x)$?

Apparently, not as the solution from Wolfram [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y''%2B4y'%2B5y%3Dsinx) doesn't multiply the particular solution by $x$. But why?

Comment: $\cos x$ doesn't appear in the solution to the homogeneous part *alone*. It does not solve the homogeneous equation.

Comment: In the CF, there's a term $e^{-2x}\cos x$. That's not the same as $\cos(x)$. The key thing here is that when you plug $A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$ into $y^{\prime\prime}+4y^\prime+5y$, it doesn't give zero. That means there'll be terms involving $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ left over, and you can compare coefficients with $\cos(x)$ to find $A$ and $B$.

If you want practice with this type of question, there's an ODE example generator here: http://www.dr-mikes-maths.com/ode-examples.html